# android 2.3.3 emulator - classnotfoundexception after moveTasToBack(true) and reopen

Tags: android

I have a one-activity application running in my emulator.  There is a menu item "Close" which calls moveTaskToBack(true);  This works fine.  However, when I clicked the app's icon to reopen the activity I get a ClassNotFoundException as it says it cannot find the activity.  This has never happened to me on other applications.  Is there an emulator problem or is it my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, somehow I the application is installed twice on my emulator.  One icon works, one doesn't.  Thanks for your responses!